# Web service to retrieve SharePoint List item

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, webservice-client

We have one SharePoint Server and another server which is having our web service (SharePoint not installed on the machine). We are trying to access SharePoint server list items using our web service. We are getting count of list items but when we go for CAML query, it returns 0 items.

How can we proceed for getting the list item?

here is our code for your reference.

```
List Device_List = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MasterList");
                      context.Load(Device_List);
                      context.ExecuteQuery();
                      int position = Device_List.ItemCount;

                    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
                    query.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='key' /><Value Type='Text'>ConTransDB</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
                    ListItemCollection itemCollection = Device_List.GetItems(query);
                    context.Load(itemCollection);
                      context.ExecuteQuery();
                      if (itemCollection.Count > 0 && itemCollection != null)
                      {
                          string value = itemCollection[0]["value"].ToString();
                      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewXml` is not complete, it requires you to define the complete view, not just the query. So it would look like:

```
query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where>...</Where></Query></View>";
```

You can even add more info than just the query, for example:

```
<View>
  <Query>
    <Where>...</Where>
    <OrderBy>...</OrderBy>
  </Query>
  <RowLimit>...</RowLimit>      
  <ViewFields>...</ViewFields>
</View>
```

Comment: Hi there, i tried using the comments you mentioned but still i am not getting the output

Comment: Can you edit the post with your updated code? Then, if it still does not work, it would be interesting, how your list is defined.

Comment: Also the same code executes properly if i mention the credentials of my farm admin. But it is not recommended to mention the farm admin credentials so i need a solution which will work this code with farm admin previleges

Comment: The user just needs to have read permissions to the list, have you checked, if the user executing the code, can access the list?

Comment: Yes, user is having read permission over the site as well as over the list. Also user is able to get the list but when i use caml query to retrieve specific item, it is getting failed

Comment: Are there items in the list, which have single permissions, which do not inherit from the list permissions? Or is versioning activated and the list items are not published yet? You said, using the CAML as a farm administrator returns the correct results?

Comment: There are no item specific permissions. Other users are having read access to entire list